# A puzzling result of "FullSimplify"

Tags: simplifying-expressions

When I input:

```
FullSimplify[(1 - a^2)/b^2, a^2 + b^2 == 1]
```

the result is the ideal answer 1；

However，if I input:

```
FullSimplify[(1 - b^2)/a^2, a^2 + b^2 == 1]
```

the result is `(1 - b^2)/a^2`， instead of the ideal answer 1. How to get the correct answer 1?

Comment: Since you are using an equality, how about using `ReplaceAll`;
`FullSimplify[((1 - a^2)/b^2) /. a -> Sqrt[1 - b^2]]` ?

Comment: It seems  like that we should need manual deduction to get the  specific variable expressions  in advance...

Comment: Somewhat related (notice those links in the comments): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25182/1871

Comment: In the `Possible Issues` item of the Documentation for `FullSimplify`, it is explicitly stated that *Results of simplification may depend on the names of symbols*.

Comment: @AlexanderZeng Side note: this "possible issue" seems to be added _recently_,  it's not included in the document of v9.0.1……

Answer (score 9):

```
Simplify[(1 - a^2)/b^2, a^2 + b^2 == 1]

(*  1  *)

Simplify[(1 - b^2)/a^2, a^2 + b^2 == 1]

(*  (1 - b^2)/a^2  *)
```

The result returned from some of Mathematica's internal algorithm's can sometimes be affected by the canonical order of the variables involved. Your problem is an example.

To reverse the canonical order

```
switchOrder = {a -> d, b -> c};

soln = Simplify @@ ({(1 - b^2)/a^2, a^2 + b^2 == 1} /. switchOrder)

(*  1  *)
```

Although in this case it is not necessary to return to the original variables, this would generally be required. To return to the original variables

```
soln /. (Reverse /@ switchOrder)

(*  1  *)
```

**EDIT:** See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124161/9362) for another example

Comment: Is there any experience about when the canonical order seems to be important? Of course, in this case it is easy to spot, but it seems that one would "always" need to switch orders and compare results of `Simplify` if it doesn't return what one wants...?

Comment: @Lukas - undoubtedly, this is not done automatically since there would be a performance cost and would generally not help or not change the form of the result enough to be worth the cost--likewise for manual application. Consequently, it should only be investigated if there is reason to believe that a more preferred form should exist or one is building a component that needs to be highly optimized & it is worth the effort to ensure that you have discovered the highest performance form. Note that the problem compounds with the number of variables--we were only dealing with two variables here.