# PrincipalValue integral returning different answers for different symbols, 11.1

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am running Mathematica 11.1 on an Ubuntu machine and noticed the following unsavory behaviour today:

```
In[1] := Assuming[ Element[x,Reals],
          Integrate[1/(1 + y^2)*1/(y - x), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
          PrincipalValue -> True]
         ]
Out[1] = Log[(-1)^(1/(1 + x^2)) e^(π /(I - x))]

In[2] := Assuming[ Element[w,Reals],
          Integrate[1/(1 + y^2)*1/(y - w), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
          PrincipalValue -> True]
         ]
Out[2] = -π w/(1+w^2)
```

Although the two answers are mathematically equivalent, it is not clear to me why the results are presented in different manners (and different enough that `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` does not reveal the latter from the former.

Clearly the answer should not depend on what symbol I use, but it does. I have obtained the same result using different kernels on the same computer. I could not reproduce the problem on Mathematica 8.0 or Mathematica 10.0 on two different Linux machines.

Is this perhaps an issue with my machine/setup? I would also like to know if others can reproduce this issue. I would also like to know if this issue persists in 11.2, if it does not I will upgrade.

Note: I believe that this is a different issue than covered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124159/integral-depends-on-choice-of-symbols) since using `u`,`v`, or `z` gives the same problem as `x`; only `w` seems to work as desired.

Answer (score 4):

They're equivalent:

```
Assuming[Element[x, Reals], 
 Integrate[1/(1 + y^2)*1/(y - x), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True]]
% // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &
(*
  Log[(-1)^(1/(1 + x^2)) E^(π/(I - x))]
  -((π x)/(1 + x^2))
*)
```

[*Updated discussion:*] I don't know why it depends on the variable name.  Symbolic algebra algorithms can depend on the order of variables (affects what is done first sometimes), but I don't see why that would matter here. It's hard to see why `w`, `i`, and `l` are special cases, but it could depend on internal variables.  (For instance `π` is converted to a internal variable by `Integrate`, and so are `x` and `w`.)  As to whether it is a bug, for my own part, I do not want `Integrate` spending a lot of time simplifying the result.  I can do that if I need to.  However, there is a significant difference timing between the two and that is troubling.  I would rather have the faster way, which coincidentally gives the simpler answer.  (Each of the following was executed on a fresh kernel, after executing `Integrate[1/(x^4 + 1), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]` to preload some internal integration code.)

```
Assuming[Element[w, Reals], 
  Integrate[1/(1 + y^2)*1/(y - w), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True]] //
   AbsoluteTiming
(*  {1.43769, -((π w)/(1 + w^2))}  *)

Assuming[Element[x, Reals], 
  Integrate[1/(1 + y^2)*1/(y - x), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, PrincipalValue -> True]] //
   AbsoluteTiming
(*  {2.42338, Log[(-1)^(1/(1 + x^2)) E^(π/(I - x))]}  *)
```

It's not a bug in the sense of giving invalid output, but from a user's point of view, it seems undesirable.

---

For what it's worth, here's the same problem, which is the source of the difference in answers but not in the difference in timing:

```
Limit[-((π (2 I + w))/(2 (1 + w^2))) - (π w)/(2 + 2 w^2) -
   (-2 w ArcTan[eps - w] - 2 Log[-eps] + Log[1 + (-eps + w)^2])/(2 + 2 w^2) +
   (2 w ArcTan[eps + w] - 2 Log[eps] + Log[1 + (eps + w)^2])/(2 + 2 w^2),
  eps -> 0, Analytic -> False, Assumptions -> {w ∈ Reals}, 
  Direction -> Automatic, 
  Method -> "InternalClassic"] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.403682, -((π w)/(1 + w^2))}  *)

Limit[-((π (2 I + x))/(2 (1 + x^2))) - (π x)/(2 + 2 x^2) -
   1/(2 + 2 x^2) (-2 x ArcTan[eps - x] - 2 Log[-eps] + Log[1 + (-eps + x)^2]) +
   1/(2 + 2 x^2) (2 x ArcTan[eps + x] - 2 Log[eps] + Log[1 + (eps + x)^2]),
  eps -> 0, Analytic -> False, Assumptions -> {x ∈ Reals}, 
  Direction -> Automatic, 
  Method -> "InternalClassic"] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.202505, Log[(-1)^(1/(1 + x^2)) E^(π/(I - x))]}  *)
```

Comment: I agree they are equivalent. I don't see how order of variables matters here since I can use symbols (where the `x` is) who come before and after x which do not work (except `w`). I'm mainly curious if this is a bug that was introduced in 11.1 and not fixed in 11.2 or if it was fixed in 11.2 (since it does not appear to exist before 11.1).

Comment: @JeremyUpsal The same happens in v10.4. Interestingly, the `y` can be any character, but only `i`, `l` and `w` as the parameter give the simpler form.

Comment: @corey979, `i` and `l` do not give the simpler form in v11.1.

Comment: Strange: If I change the assumption on `x` to `x > 2.78215965`, then we get the simpler form, but not if I use `x > 2.78215964`.

Comment: @JeremyUpsal Could you check the timings for the two integrals on your system?  I'm using V11.2, and I'm curious if you get the same results. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelE2 My timing is 0.746089 and 1.5535 for w and x respectively. If I change the assumption to `x>2.78215965` the time increases to 1.66046 but gives the simpler form. If I change the assumption to `x>2.78215964` the time increases more to 1.72901 and does not give the correct form.

Answer (score 4):

Since both answers are equivalent, there is no bug. The algorithm merely provides different representations due to some internal choice(s).

```
$Version

"11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)"

Assuming[Element[#, Reals], 
   Integrate[1/(1 + y^2)*1/(y - #), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    PrincipalValue -> True]] & /@ {a, b, i, l, t, v, w, x, z}

(* {Log[(-1)^(1/(1 + a^2))*E^(Pi/(I - a))], 
   Log[(-1)^(1/(1 + b^2))*E^(Pi/(I - b))], 
   Log[(-1)^(1/(1 + i^2))*E^(Pi/(I - i))], 
   Log[(-1)^(1/(1 + l^2))*E^(Pi/(I - l))], 
   Log[(-1)^(1/(1 + t^2))*E^(Pi/(I - t))], 
   Log[(-1)^(1/(1 + v^2))*E^(Pi/(I - v))], 
   -((Pi*w)/(1 + w^2)), 
   Log[(-1)^(1/(1 + x^2))*E^(Pi/(I - x))], 
   Log[(-1)^(1/(1 + z^2))*E^(Pi/(I - z))]} *)
```

To get the simplified form for each

```
Assuming[Element[#, Reals], 
   Integrate[1/(1 + y^2)*1/(y - #), {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
      PrincipalValue -> True] // 
     ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify] & /@ 
  {a, b, i, l, t, v, w, x, z}

(* {-((a*Pi)/(1 + a^2)), -((b*Pi)/(1 + b^2)), -((i*Pi)/(1 + i^2)), 
   -((l*Pi)/(1 + l^2)), -((Pi*t)/(1 + t^2)), -((Pi*v)/(1 + v^2)), 
   -((Pi*w)/(1 + w^2)), -((Pi*x)/(1 + x^2)), -((Pi*z)/(1 + z^2))} *)
```